# How to get unigram and trigram only?

Tags: r, data-analysis

I need to get the unigrame and trigram without bigrame

```
trigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 1, max = 3))
```

how to edit this code to get the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use the `dfm` function from `quanteda` package as follows,

```
library(quanteda)
dfm('I only want uni and trigrams', ngrams = c(1,3), verbose = FALSE)

#Document-feature matrix of: 1 document, 10 features.
#1 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
#       features
#docs    i only want uni and trigrams i_only_want only_want_uni want_uni_and uni_and_trigrams
#  text1 1    1    1   1   1        1           1             1            1                1
```